# How do I indent the text after the first line in a block of text?

Tags: lists, indentation

I would like the content of the second and following lines of the entries below to indent enough spaces so that they appear after the date. The idea is to make a list of publications easier to read. Maybe a "tab" command? I'm not sure. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{res} % Use the res.cls style, the font size can be changed to 11pt or 12pt here
\usepackage{helvet} 
\newsectionwidth{0pt} % Stops section indenting

\begin{document}

11/2012: From chickens to parakeets: How (and why) ghosts from the past possess our birds until today. ``Death, dying, and the Great Beyond'' Conference at the Institute for Paranormal Animal Embodiment – Russian Academy of Sciences, Saint Petersburg, Russia.

11/2012: From chickens to parakeets: How (and why) ghosts from the past possess our birds until today. ``Death, dying, and the Great Beyond'' Conference at the Institute for Paranormal Animal Embodiment – Russian Academy of Sciences, Saint Petersburg, Russia.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `res` class would use `\section{11/2012}` leaving this on a line by itself; you don't get any indentation in the text because *you* are setting it to zero. Note: the `res` class doesn't know the option 10pt (it's the default, but specifying it produces an annoying warning). There are various classes or packages for CV, more recent than `res.cls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `itemize` environments are for.  I create `\lftfieldwidth{string}` to pass a (longest) string to define the left field width for that `itemize` environment.  Also, dates will be right-justified in that field by default.  To make them left justified, pass the argument of the `\item` as `\lft{}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{res} % Use the res.cls style, the font size can be changed to 11pt or 12pt here
\usepackage{helvet} 
\usepackage{calc}
\newsectionwidth{0pt} % Stops section indenting

\newlength\lftboxwidth
\newcommand\lft[1]{%
  \makebox[\lftboxwidth][l]{#1}%
}
\newcommand\lftfieldwidth[1]{%
  \setlength\lftboxwidth{\widthof{#1}}%
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{\lftboxwidth+\widthof{~}}%
}
\begin{document}
\lftfieldwidth{11/2012:}
\begin{itemize}
\item[11/2012:] This tag has the maximum width, which is used to set \verb|\lftfieldwidth|

\item[1/2012:] This tag is right justified, by default

\item[\lft{1/2012:}] This tag is left justified, using \verb|\lft|

\item[\lft{1/1111:}] From chickens to parakeets: How (and why) ghosts from the past possess our birds until today. ``Death, dying, and the Great Beyond'' Conference at the Institute for Paranormal Animal Embodiment – Russian Academy of Sciences, Saint Petersburg, Russia.
\end{itemize}

\noindent Normal left margin
\end{document}
```

[image]